# Error con Vistas de MySQL en Backend de Angular9

Tags: mysql, nodejs, angular, typescript, backend

Tengo un Backend desarrollado en Angular9. Esto se conecta a una base de datos en MySQL en la que realiza consultas a tablas y vistas. Local en mi PC con Windows funciona bien. En un servidor Debian me arroja un error de que no puede encontrar la vista, la vista existe y desde MySQL funciona bien.

```
 "result": null,
"err": null,
"message": {
    "body": {
        "code": "ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE",
        "errno": 1146,
        "sqlMessage": "Table 'piab_database.pre_license_view' doesn't exist",
        "sqlState": "42S02",
        "index": 0,
        "sql": "SELECT * FROM `pre_license_view`"
    },
    "status": 500,
    "message": "Ha ocurrido un error en su peticion"
```

Que pudiera ocasionar este error? Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulta que el usuario con el que me conectaba a la db era admin pero por alguna razón no tenía permiso sobre vistas y por eso no las veia... cree un usuario con acceso solo local para esa base de datos solamente (una practica recomendada) y a ese le otorgue todos los permisos sobre esta.. Espero que les solucione el problema a otros... saludos...

Comment: Que bueno que hayas solucionado tu problema, y gracias también por compartir la solución!